# How do you link the value of a checkbox to another checkbox

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, data-validation

I am using the checkbox feature in Google Sheets and I have another checkbox that I would like to be ticked when the original one is ticked.

I tried using the formula where the original checkbox is A1 and the secondary checkbox is B4 I would enter the formula `=A1` in the B4 formula field, however, this just inserts the value `true` not a ticked checkbox.

Comment: can you provide a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Will  you need that the "another checkbox" **works** as a checkbox or just that **looks** as a checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done via "standard" means. Formulas are not permitted as custom checked/unchecked values.

here is one of many methods of how to fake it:

- decide on cell height / width / color / background color
- insert checkbox
- zoom in via browser zoom **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>+</kbd>**
- take a screenshot (ticked and unticked)
- photoshop it (count for the frame around checkbox)
- upload it (preferably on your Google Drive to minimalize update lag response)
- and then use a simple `IF` statement to insert those images based on another checkbox

[image]

```
=IF(E23=1;   
    IMAGE("https://i.imgur.com/DgTwvYi.png");
    IMAGE("https://i.imgur.com/8AxCgKZ.png"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The image answer got me thinking and this seems to work best.

- Insert a checkbox in each cell you want them located
- Use your arrow key to move to the box you want to be linked
  You will notice the formula box shows FALSE if unchecked
- Type the following into the cell, A1 representing the controlling box location

  `=IF(A1=TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)`